# Need to eliminate the last 4 characters in a string(varchar)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

i am using a stored procedure, where it is taking policy number as parameter which is varchar. I need to eliminate the last 4 characters of the policy number when we retrive from the tables. But the data for policy numbers is not consistent, so I am confused how to use the logic for this. The sample policy numbers are:

1. KSDRE0021-000
2. APDRE-10-21-000
3. KSDRE0021
4. APDRE-10-21

These are four formats where policies are there in our tables.For some policies there is no tailing end '-000', so that is the challenging part. Now, I need to eliminate the tailing part '-000' from the policies when I retrieve the data from tables.

This is the sample code, which is pulling the policy data from tables.

```
Create Proc usp.dbo.policydataSP @policy_num varchar(18)
AS
Begin
Select * from policy_table pt
where pt.policy_num = @policy_num
End
```

Comment: seems like the problem is not stripping on the last 4, since sometimes it is 10 characters. Maybe what you want is just the first 5 characters?

Answer (score 2):

**STEP 1:** Create a User Defined Function to normalize a policy number.

```
create function dbo.normalize_policy_num
    (@policy_num varchar(100))
returns varchar(100)
as
begin

    -- replace trailing digits
    if (@policy_num like '%-[0-9][0-9][0-9]')
        set @policy_num = left(@policy_num, len(@policy_num) - 4)

    -- replace remaining hyphens
    set @policy_num = replace(@policy_num, '-', '')

    return @policy_num

end
```

What this essentially doing is stripping off the trailing '-000' from policy numbers that contain the pattern, then removing remaining hyphens.  This function seems to work on your supplied policy numbers:

```
-- returns: KSDRE0021
select dbo.normalize_policy_num('KSDRE0021-000')

-- returns: APDRE1021
select dbo.normalize_policy_num('APDRE-10-21-000')

-- returns: KSDRE0021
select dbo.normalize_policy_num('KSDRE0021')

-- returns: APDRE1021
select dbo.normalize_policy_num('APDRE-10-21')
```

**STEP 2:** Modify your SP as follows:

```
create proc usp.dbo.policydataSP
    @policy_num varchar(18)
as
begin

select
    dbo.normalize_policy_num(pt.policy_num) as normalized_policy_num,
    pt.*
from policy_table pt
where dbo.normalize_policy_num(@policy_num) = dbo.normalize_policy_num(pt.policy_num)
```

**Note:** If you are able to modify the table schema, you could add a persisted computed column using the UDF specified above.  If you add an index to it, queries will run much faster.  However, there will be some penalty for inserts, so there is a trade-off.

Comment: i think you misunderstand. The extra characters are in the table, not the parameter.

Comment: the last four digits '-000' is also not consistent, it may vary all the time. like sometimes it might be -012, -142, -001. In that case how the above given code will work? how can we modify that to?

Comment: Please see my updated answer.  I think I got most of the corner cases here :)

Comment: +1 alone for creating a function. A lot of people think placing the logic in one query is the best method, but, even in a one-off, keeping it in one place makes modifications consistent. And, for something like this, it's bound to come up elsewhere (and now you have a go-to method with a single maintenance point).

Answer (score 0):

this is probably your best bet. Match the policy number up to the length of the requested parameter:

```
Create Proc usp.dbo.policydataSP 
    @policy_num varchar(18) 
AS 
Begin 
    Select * from policy_table pt where LEFT(len(@policy_num),pt.policy_num) = @policy_num 
End
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to strip `-000` when returning results:

```
select case right(policy_num, 4)
            when '-000' then left(policy_num, len(policy_num) - 4)
            else policy_num end as policy_num
  from policy_table pt
 where pt.policy_num = @policy_num
```

If you want to strip any 3-digit value following a dash:

```
select case when policy_num like '%-[0-9][0-9][0-9]' then left(policy_num, len(policy_num) - 4)
            else policy_num end as policy_num
  from policy_table pt
 where pt.policy_num = @policy_num
```